# Display custom block on category or product page only if user is logged in and is joining some specific groups

Tags: php, magento

I want to show the content of a magento static block on product page and maybe also on product listing page.

Static block will be visible only for `LOGGED IN USERS` that are joining specific groups (eg. `logged in` users that are inside `reseller`, `general` and `clients`, not inside `testing` or `guests`).

P.S. I need to add it also in sidebar, where I have layered navigation.

Comment: hey luca.please check  my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array =[1,2,3]; //your group ids array
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
 $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
  $groupId = $customerData->getGroupId();
if(in_array($groupId,$array)){
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
}
}
```

place above code in template name below

frontend/[your-theme]/[your-package]/catalog/product/view.phtml

frontend/[your-theme]/[your-package]/catalog/product/list.phtml

frontend/[your-theme]/[your-package]/catalog/layer/view.phtml

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do this easyly.

**Step1:** Create template `showstatic.phtml` at a`pp/design/frondtend/YourPackage/YourPackage/template/cms/`

**Step2:** on this phtml,you can check customer loggin in  and it group id then using show Static block.

**code is :**

```
<?php 
        $loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
        // add Handler when customer is loggedin
        if($loggedIn):
            $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
             //Get customer Group name

             $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

             $Groupcode=$group->getData('customer_group_code');
             /* static  customer group code array for which static block will call */
             $Enableforgroup=array(13, 2, 8, 7);  // call static array
            if (in_array($Groupcode, $Enableforgroup)){
                echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();
            }

        endif;

?>
```

Now you to call this phtml at category,product by

**Category:**

Category page at `app/design/frondtend/YourPackage/YourPackage/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('cms/showstatic.phtml')->toHtml();
```

**Product:**

Product page at `app/design/frondtend/YourPackage/YourPackage/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('cms/showstatic.phtml')->toHtml();
```

### AS magento process:

Create `local.xml` file at `app/design/frondtend/YourPackage/YourPackage/layout/`

**Code is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!--  add this handler for show all category   pages -->
    <catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="content"> 
    <!--  reference block for page where you want show
    the static block
     -->
        <block type="core/template" name="showstatic" template="cms/showstatic.phtml">
             <block type="cms/block" name="showstatichow" >
                        <!--
                            The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                            You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                        -->
                        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_company</block_id></action>
             </block>

        </block>
    </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>


        <!--  add this handler for show all product   pages -->
    <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content"> 
    <!--  reference block for page where you want show
    the static block
     -->
        <block type="core/template" name="showstatic" template="cms/showstatic.phtml">
             <block type="cms/block" name="showstatichow" >
                        <!--
                            The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                            You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                        -->
                        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_company</block_id></action>
             </block>

        </block>
    </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>


</layout>
```

Create template file `showstatic.phtml` at a`pp/design/frondtend/YourPackage/YourPackage/template/cms/`

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
// show cms blocks   when customer is loggedin
if($loggedIn):
    // get Customer group id from session
    echo $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    /*   $Enableforgroup is array for reseller, general and clients
     *  group ids
     */
    $Enableforgroup=array(13, 2, 1, 7);  // call static array
    if (in_array($groupId, $Enableforgroup)){
        echo $this->getChildHtml("showstatichow");
    }


endif;

?>
```

Comment: Please note that, even if this answer may actually solve the OP question, this is going to introduce a lot of logic into a view, which is a really bad practice in a MVC framework like Magento.

Comment: I know  that but for quick reference .. I have put the code  in this process

Comment: Ok, then it looks like you do not understand Magento MVC correctly. View = `.pthml` files. So here are building logic (which belongs to block or controller) in a view.